# Accessing the event path of any fired event of many event types when watching files in Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, chokidar

With Gulp, you can access the path of a fired event by using the [`watch().on()` method](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch/#chokidar-instance) for each event type:

```js
const { watch } = require('gulp');

watch('*.js').on('change', (path, stats) => {
  console.log(`File ${path} was changed`);
});

watch('*.js').on('add', (path, stats) => {
  console.log(`File ${path} was added`);
});
```

You can also watch for multiple event types using the [`events` option](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch/#options), but you don't get access to the path of a fired event:

```js
watch('*.js', { events: ['change', 'add'] }, cb => {
  // body omitted
  cb();
});
```

Is there a way to access the path of a fired event from a single anonymous handler when watching for multiple event types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could watch for all events and, as needed, filter out the events later in the callback.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');

const watcher = gulp.watch(['*.js']);

gulp.task('default', function() {
  watcher.on('all', function(event, path, stats) {
    console.log(`File ${path} was ${event}`);
    console.log(stats);
    // filter some things using the event param if needed
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that different event types send different arguments to the callback. The Gulp docs imply that `path` and `stats` are sent for all of them, and so I didn't think to confirm with the Chokidar docs.